# billing system with multiple profile PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

My latest project is to build a billing system with multiple profile like 
100+ training institutes connected with this system for their online front base management purpose.

**like..**

*Counseling

*Admission

*Billing

etc..

now what i want to know whether to keep a single database for all the operations or its better to maintain individual database for individual organization/profile.

well i'm kind a lost here just need a kick start.

i am using MySQL as database and PHP as my server side scripting language.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your institutes are totally isolated, so you never want to get data from a different institute or any kind of summation over all institutes and if you're not planning to automatically create a new institue, you can use one database for each.

But I don't see any advantage in this and suggest to just use one database and have a column `institute_id` in each table. Access control will of course be in your PHP code.

Comment: well the `institute_id` is very good though, and gives a nice layouting overall..

but can i know the advantage and disadvantage if i use individual db?

Comment: I don't see any convincing reason. You wouldn't have to filter with `institute_id` in every table. You would do this by selecting the institute's database. But compared to all the disadvantages, this seems irrelevant.